# Error when running simple script containing local function in Octave

Tags: octave

My file testtest.m looks like :

```
pluse(1, 2)
function retval = pluse(input1, input2)
retval = input1 + input2;
endfunction
```

Then I get:

```
error: 'pluse' undefined near line 1 column 1
error: called from
    testtest at line 1 column 1
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: Your file should have a name 'pluse.m'

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but doing so causes the error "invalid use of script ~/Octave/pluse.m in index expression". I really don't know why this isn't working as I imagine this is a basic feature of Octave. (I use Octave 4.0.0, is it a problem?)

Comment: This is basic matlab / octave syntax. a) functions are typically defined in their own files, b) if you'd like to define a function on-the-spot, you need to define it before you can use it c) a script file may not start with a 'function' statement since this is reserved for function files. See https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Functions-and-Scripts.html#Functions-and-Scripts and https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Function-Files.html#Function-Files and https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Script-Files.html#Script-Files in particular.

Comment: Thank you Tasos. So it is different from MATLAB, where you can run the code above. In Octave, you need to do:
[[[[ 1;
function retval = pluse(input1, input2)
retval = input1 + input2;
endfunction
pluse(1, 2)  ]]]] , which is slightly awkward, I believe.

Comment: Hi Martin. Please use a 'tag' when replying (e.g. @TasosPapastylianou) otherwise I don't get a notification (whereas the owner of a thread, i.e. you, gets notified automatically for new comments, whether they are tagged or not). I don't think it's different for matlab; maybe for the very latest version. Older versions didn't even support 'on-the-spot' function definitions like this, whereas octave has supported them for years, so maybe matlab's recent implementation allows this by accident (or on purpose to mess with octave, hahah). I don't think it should though, let me check at work ...

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question properly, I need to point out two things:

1. The canonical way to create a function in both octave and matlab is by placing it in a dedicated file by the same name, and starting the file with a *function declaration*. The corollary of this is that any file in the path that starts with a function declaration is detected at start-up and made available to the user as a callable function.
2. Octave has supported 'on-the-go' function definitions for many years (and in fact also supports subsequent 'exporting' of such 'on-the-go' functions to files); matlab has only included 'on-the-go' functionality very recently (2016b I believe?), and has chosen to implement this somewhat differently than octave, ( presumably to keep octave on its toes? :p )

Octave's implementation effectively follows straightforwardly from the rules of the language. Any file that starts with a statement that *isn't* a 'function declaration' is treated as a script, i.e. a sequence of independent statements. Hence the innocuous `1` at the start of your script which is as simple a 'non-function-declaration' statement as it gets, but really it could be anything. A script can then have as many 'on-the-go' function definitions as desired. For a statement to make use of a function in an 'on-the-go' context, the function clearly needs to have been defined first. This follows from the fundamental principle that a script, in contrast to a function, effectively represents a simple collection of statements that are run in sequence without any pre-processing, and that one could expect to simply copy/paste these commands to or from their terminal and expect them to run.

Matlab's recent implementation effectively breaks this functionality / paradigm. To see what I mean, copy paste your code above into a fresh terminal (or highlight then press F9) and watch it break. A script is no longer copy/pasteable, but assumes matlab will read ahead and load up any function definitions *first*, and *then* go back and try to run the remaining commands; in other words, matlab now kinda treats scripts like it does its functions. Note that matlab still also requires a script to start with a non-function-declaration statement, so effectively this bit is the same as octave needing to start with a '1'. The only thing that's changed is this look-ahead behaviour for preemptively loading 'on-the-go' functions, which I would argue isn't necessarily a good thing in the context of scripts.

I would argue that Octave's approach makes more sense, despite the convenience you point out with matlab when (unintentionally) treating a script as effectively not a script. Which one presumably shouldn't do in the first place. If you need look-ahead functionality and nesting, you really should be writing a proper function and providing relevant scoping context in the first place.

Comment: I've posted this a feature request on the Octave issue tracker – https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?56187 – and submitted it as a Matlab feature request to MathWorks support. Maybe some day we'll see unification.

Comment: I'd argue that Matlab's approach is at least consistent: Matlab's paradigm for function definitions is declarative and not procedural. Unlike some dynamic languages, functions don't pop into existence when a `function` statement is executed. They're just always there, by virtue of their existence somewhere on the filesystem, or inside a classdef or function definition file (or as a nested function within a function). This is nice because you don't have to worry about "when" they get defined. It is a bummer that you can't define script local functions near their point of use, though.

Comment: Here's another thought: maybe Matlab requires local functions to be at the end of a script to differentiate them from nested functions, which are closures that capture references to variables inside their containing function. Maybe there's a possibility for supporting nested functions inside a script, too, which capture variables in the script body, and Matlab wants to reserve that syntactic case.

Answer (score 2):

[I had the same question/problem and some people gave the hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51417342/does-octave-support-local-functions). But since there is no explicit example, I post it here so that other guys can find a explict running example both for Octave and MATLAB.

```
% works in Octave %%%
% sth. must be *before* a (local) function is declared
1; % or "2;" or "1+1;" or whatever

% local function must be declared *before* it is run in Octave
function retval = pluse(input1, input2)
  retval = input1 + input2;
end % or "endfunction"

% Now you can use the local function
pluse(1, 2)
```

And there the the incompatibility between Octave and MATLAB because the MATLAB example does not run in Octave and vice versa:

```
% works in MATLAB %%%
% You can use the local function
pluse(1, 2)

% local function must be declared at the end of file for MATLAB
function retval = pluse(input1, input2)
  retval = input1 + input2;
end
```

Because of this incompatibility the question is if one should really use local functions. A solution that work for both Octave and MATLAB is to use "normal" functions in another file...