# Does octave support local functions?

Tags: octave

Am I correct that "local functions" (https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions-in-scripts.html#bvfvxg0) are not possible in Octave (4.4.0) like:

```
data = 1:10;            %# A vector of data
squaredData = f(data);  %# Invoke the local function

function y = f(x)
  y = x.^2;
end
```

I get the error

```
error: 'f' undefined near line 2 column 15
```

Comment: you need to declare the function before you make use of it. And if you want it to remain a script, your first statement can't be a function definition. The canonical start of a script is `1;`

Comment: Also, as a point of pride, octave's support for local functions far predates those of matlab. I can't be sure which octave version first introduced them (if not from the beginning), but we're probably talking decades here. Matlab simply chose an incompatible implementation when they finally introduced them to Matlab in 2016, because, well, of course they would, why wouldn't they.

Comment: have a look at the [Functions and Scripts](https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Functions-and-Scripts.html#Functions-and-Scripts) chapter in the manual, and [this](https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Script-Files.html#Script-Files) in particular.

Comment: Also, my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50507980/4183191) on this same topic, if you're interested.

Comment: I guess I followed https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Script-Files.html#Script-Files (without knowing) since there is not the word "function" in the first line: It is no "1;" but I have "data = 1:10;" instead. And I do not run the local function in the first line as in the "duplicate question". So, why does this code not run in octave or what must be changed?

Comment: @tardis you need to declare your functions *before* you call them.

Comment: Thanks. The octave documentation gives no explicit example and I cannot add it here since it is a duplicate. So I gave an explicit answer with the example for both Octave and MATLAB in https://stackoverflow.com/a/51441125/3021134