# This code gives me a plot in Matlab but not in Octave

Tags: octave, matlab-figure, octave-gui

The code works fine and gives me the plot when I run it in Matlab but it doesn't give me any output in Octave, please help.
(The code is for generating a 2D lattice and it should output a plot)

```
function generate_2dlattice_p4mm()
n1=[-2:1:2];
n2=[-2:1:2];
n3=[-2:1:2];
V=[2 0 0; 0 2 0; 0 0 0];
basis=getbasis();
[nb]=size(basis);
atom = 1;
for k= 1:length(n1)
    for l=1:length(n2)
        for m=1:length(n3)
          for b=1:nb
            H= V(1,:)*n1(k) + V(2,:)*n2(l) + ...
            V(3,:)*n3(m) + basis(b,1)*V(1,:) + basis(b,2)*V(2,:) + basis(b,3)*V(3,:);
            
            X(atom) = H(1);
            Y(atom) = H(2);
            Z(atom) = H(3);
            
            atom = atom + 1;
          end
        end
      end
    end
 plot3(X,Y,Z,'o','MarkerFaceColor','r','MarkerSize',20);

end

function [b]=getbasis()
  bg1=[0.2 0.3 0; 1-0.2 1-0.3 0; 1-0.3 0.2 0;0.3 1-0.2 0;...
         1-0.2 0.3 0; 0.2 1-0.3 0; 0.3 0.2 0; 1-0.3 1-0.2 0];
  bg2=[0.1 0.3 0; 1-0.1 1-0.3 0; 1-0.3 0.1 0; 0.3 1-0.1 0;...
         1-0.1 0.3 0; 0.1 1-0.3 0; 0.3 0.1 0; 1-0.3 1-0.1 0];
  be=[0.3 0.5 0; 1-0.3 0.5 0; 0.5 0.3 0; 0.5 1-0.3 0]
  bc=[0.5 0 0; 0 0.5 0]
  ba=[0 0 0];
  b=[bg1;bg2;be;bc;ba];
end
```

Comment: You mean like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvxW5.png)? This is what comes out if I run your code. Is this not what you expect?

Comment: yes, that is what i got when i ran it in matlab, i just wanted to know why the same code did not give me an output/plot in octave.

Comment: The plot I posted was generated in octave from this code. Perhaps you are using some weird way of running your script instead of creating a function file and just running it? E.g. relying on 'inline' function definitions and falling victim to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55812060/4183191)?  Incidentally, octave throws a very reasonable warning when running the code; apparently you're trying to do `for b = 1 : [23,3]` which makes no sense, so you've probably got a logical error there (you probably meant for `b = nb`?)

Comment: i've rewritten the file name to something else and it gave me a plot, i don't know why,but thank you.

Comment: Is it possible that you had originally written this function without the plotting part enabled, run it, and then modified the file, and tried running it again without first doing a `clear functions`? I think Octave, unlike Matlab, requires you to do a `clear functions` to pick up changes to function definitions. Writing it to a new file would have caused it to load the new modified version regardless of whether `clear functions` was done.