# Do functions always require their own separate files?

Tags: function, octave

I am trying to run a script I found on a pdf that requires defining a function `tor.m`

This is the script for the function:

```
function xp=tor(t,x)
xp=zeros(4,1);
xp(1)=x(2);
xp(2)=-(2+cos(x(1)))*sin(x(1))*x(4)^2;
xp(3)=x(4);
xp(4)=2*(sin(x(1))/(2+cos(x(1))))*x(2)*x(4);
```

I tried defining the function within the rest of the script, as I would in R or Python, but it doesn't seem to work.

**Do functions always require their own separate files in Matlab / Octave? Can I include both the function and the rest of the code in one single file?**

Here is the rest of the code:

```
[u,v]=meshgrid(linspace(0,2*pi,36),linspace(0,2*pi,36));
x=(2+cos(u)).*cos(v);
y=(2+cos(u)).*sin(v);
z=sin(u);

surf(x,y,z)
hold on
[t,X]=ode23s('tor',[0,20*pi] ,[pi/2,.1,-pi/2,.2]);
u=X(:,1);
v=X(:,3);
x=(2+cos(u)).*cos(v);
y=(2+cos(u)).*sin(v);
z=sin(u);
plot3(x,y,z,'-', 'color', 'y', 'MarkerSize', 50)
```

---

Error:

```
function xp=tor(t,x)
xp=zeros(4,1);
xp(1)=x(2);
xp(2)=-(2+cos(x(1)))*sin(x(1))*x(4)^2;
xp(3)=x(4);
xp(4)=2*(sin(x(1))/(2+cos(x(1))))*x(2)*x(4);
end
[u,v]=meshgrid(linspace(0,2*pi,36),linspace(0,2*pi,36));
x=(2+cos(u)).*cos(v);
y=(2+cos(u)).*sin(v);
z=sin(u);

surf(x,y,z)
hold on
[t,X]=ode23s('tor',[0,20*pi] ,[pi/2,.1,-pi/2,.2]);
u=X(:,1);
v=X(:,3);
x=(2+cos(u)).*cos(v);
y=(2+cos(u)).*sin(v);
z=sin(u);
plot3(x,y,z,'-', 'color', 'y', 'MarkerSize', 50)

>> test

warning: function name 'tor' does not agree with function filename 'C:\Users\ParellaA\Documents\Octave\test.m'
error: 'x' undefined near line 3, column 7
error: called from
    test at line 3 column 6
```

Comment: Please read the descriptions of both [tag:matlab] and [tag:octave]. They are **not** the same, thus please only use both tags when asking about the similarities/differences between the two. Using both tags could result in answers being incompatible to the other software, unnecessarily forcing answerers to check validity of their code in both programs.

Comment: In Octave you can define a function in your script, put the function definition before the point you want to call it. In MATLAB it works differently, hence Adriaan’s comment above.

Comment: “I tried defining the function within the rest of the script […], but it doesn't seem to work.” Please post the code that didn’t work, and include the full error message that indicates it didn’t work.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I just edited the OP.

Comment: Ah, I see what is going on. Please check out the linked Q&A, I think it will solve your issue.

Comment: @CrisLuengo It does work with a `1;` at the beginning. Is there a similar hack for Matlab?

Comment: In MATLAB you need to put the function definitions at the end of the script, after all the other code.

Comment: @AntoniParellada also see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55812060/4183191